# Can P&T Assets read/use image EXIF data?

Tags: assets, image

Seems like a no-brainer feature to have, specifically regarding the date and location properties of images.

And yes, I know I can use VZ Exif, but for performance reasons, I'd prefer to have that metadata in Assets' DB instead of reading the data from the filesystem every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just like to point out that, in order to read EXIF data, you must have PHP compiled using --exif-enabled flag, which is not something all hosting parties provide, hence Assets is not sporting this feature, but this is on our list of things to do, probably by using some 3rd party library for this, that parses jpg files.

Comment: Thanks, Andris... wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a feature there or something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct with the plugin "VZ EXIF", all the EXIF data are being fetched for that file dynamically. 
I couldn't see such any file handling field type which stores EXIF data also.

I think, a field type or module can be developed for it which would be great :).

Comment: You mean a fieldtype for VZ Exif? I'd rather just see Assets have EXIF data reading introduced... seems to me that adding that feature would be far easier for Assets than adding an entire file upload/management system would be for VZ Exif.

Comment: @Sandwich: It meant by having a file field type for storing EXIF data, The VZ EXIF is already developed as a plugin. Yes, if Assets having such it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it can. You'll find details in the [P&T Assets docs](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/field.html) including parameters for `date`, `date_modified`, and `location`.

Comment: Those fields you mentioned pull the metadata that Assets stores for each file, but as far as I know, that metadata isn't populated by a JPG's EXIF data.